# Manipulator joint constraints

Tags: sdformat

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi, i am trying to implement a manipulator inside gazebo, by writing my own SDF file. I have written the geometry and joint basing on existing examples, but when I spawn the robot, it goes limp. I can't seem to have control using the joints menu part, it seems no matter what input I give to the first joint, it seems to break the whole robot. I haven't calculated the inertia for different links yet, for now I used some placeholder values, might this be the source of my problem? Here is the code for the robot:
https://pastebin.com/0vAtGS8P

EDIT:
I've changed the inertia values to ones that closely resemble the real parts, but it seems that after inserting the model it just breaks, after getting in contact with the ground. Also, with the previous configuration I noticed that when I changed the position of the base_revolute joint the base part was rotating, not the whole robot.

Here is the pic of the broken model:

[image: image description]

Here is the new code:

https://pastebin.com/asvmHPG9

EDIT #2:
It seems that the problem is connected with the fourth link, but currently I can't figure out where.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/17153/manipulator-joint-constraints/) by [Fiddle](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3737/fiddle/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 35 on 2017-09-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

What Gazebo version you're using? It doesn't explode for me:

[image: image description]

In any case, before you start applying forces to your robot, it's very important you choose good inertia values, because they will determine the dynamics of your model. The explosions you mention could be caused by bad inertial properties.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2017-09-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Fiddle](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3737/fiddle/) on 2017-09-04**:
I've tried to update the inertia values, but it seems that somehow I broke the robot even further. May these problems still be caused by inertia values? (more info in the edit).